# Azure AD/Microsoft Graph API authentication implementation on web application

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I wanted to implement o365 authentication in my current project. my intention is to standardize/centralize the login of employee and the administrative staff of the portal using Microsoft O365 authentication.

I managed to test out some of the sample projects online and it seems a bit confusing cause there are different ways of authenticating.

My ideal implementation is something as the drawing below.

[image: design]

On the API gateway for employee front end portal, I wanted to implement a gateway to verify the Microsoft access_token passed and obtain the (sid / object_id) to cross check with my employee database for function access.

As for the Administrator front end portal, it will be responsible for sync-ing the users front Azure AD daily automatically or the admin trigger the sync manually.

What confuses me was there are several ways to obtain the access_token, some tokens managed to return the info i wanted but I'm not entirely sure if that is the correct implementation.
For the case of verifying and sync-ing users from azure AD, both accepting different access_token in order to get the data/information.

Anyone expert here mind to guide me to the correct path of implementing the design above if not correct the implementation ?

Comment: The one thing that sticks out to me from the drawing is the token validation in the APIs. The way it works is that your authentication component should download the metadata document from e.g. [here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration) (every tenant has their own document, this is the "common" one). The API can then use the signing keys it got from there to validate the tokens' digital signatures.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into application user roles, especially for the administrator side. Or you can use explicit user assignments without defining roles. I wrote an article on permissions and roles here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad (scroll down to User roles). Though actually you cannot have roles on the front-end, they need to be defined on the API.

Comment: Hi @juunas, sorry for the late reply. was assigned to other project and was just told to resume this project. thanks for the tips given, will read through and keep you updated. Thanks !